# Website loading with timeout, get() does not get and click() the button

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have to press the button, select different currency and then check 24 hours exchange rates then see if it's positive. I am very new to cypress and trying to learn. I have read the cypress docs, did not manage to find guidance.

This is my code so far.

```
describe('dropdown select', () => {
    it('open dropdown', () => {
    cy.visit('https://spectrocoin.com/en/bitcoin-price-rates.html')
    cy.get('[class=" css-2b097c-container"]', { timeout: 20000 })
    cy.get('button').contains('USD').click()
    })
})
```

I added the timeout of 20seconds because it seemed as if the page does not load before finding the element. But it shows a completely different element when highlighted in Cypress environment than Chrome Inspect element environment.

What may be the issue of it not finding the correct button, then selecting, lets say, EUR currency in the dropdown.

[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otayb.png)

[Current Status Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcMLy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
describe('dropdown select', () => {
  it('open dropdown', () => {
    cy.visit('https://spectrocoin.com/en/bitcoin-price-rates.html')
    Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
      return false
    }) //Ignore exceptions
    cy.get('[data-cy=accept-btn]').click()
    cy.get('#currency-select').should('be.visible').click()
  })
})
```

Instead of the class you can use the id `#currency-select` selector and this works.

Test Runner Screenshot:
[image: test runner execute]

To ignore exceptions originating from your webpage you can use this. But your webpage shouldn't throw exceptions in the first place and that your test should be able to catch those in case if it does. So it's not a good practice to use this. Instead let your test fail and ask your developers to look into it and fix it.

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

Comment: It seems to be showing an error on the line that is supposed to click the accept button.  `cy.get('[data-cy=accept-btn]').click()` . Could this be because the website is not quick enough to load and find it?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: "0 matched elements"

Comment: I ran the exact code locally and it is working for me. I have added the screenshot, int hat you can see the currency dropdown is opened. Also I saw that the webpage was throwing exceptions you have to add `Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {return false})`

Comment: Adding the exception worked. It now sucessfully click the dropdown. I will continue working on how to select the currency, then 24 hr. rates. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer.